# C++ constructor call - need help figuring how certain calls are made

Tags: c++, syntax, polymorphism

```
class PayOffBridge
{
public:

    PayOffBridge();
    PayOffBridge(const PayOffBridge& original);
    PayOffBridge(const PayOff& innerPayOff);

    inline double operator()(double Spot) const;
    ~PayOffBridge();
    PayOffBridge& operator=(const PayOffBridge& original);

private:

    PayOff* ThePayOffPtr;

};
```

and another class with a member which is an object of `class PayOffBridge`:

```
class VanillaOption
{
public:

    VanillaOption(const PayOffBridge& ThePayOff_, double Expiry);

    double OptionPayOff(double Spot) const;
    double GetExpiry() const;

private:

    double Expiry;
    PayOffBridge ThePayOff;
};
```

The `PayOff* ThePayOffPtr` in `PayOffBridge` is a pointer to the following pure virtual abstract class:

```
class PayOff
{
public:

    PayOff(){};

    virtual double operator()(double Spot) const=0;
    virtual ~PayOff(){}
    virtual PayOff* clone() const=0;

private:

};
```

The concrete class `PayOffCall` is derived from `PayOff`. In `main()` I have

```
PayOffCall thePayOff(Strike);//double Strike
VanillaOption theOption(thePayOff, Expiry);//double Expiry
```

When I step through the code using F11 in Visual Studio, the line `VanillaOption theOption(thePayOff, Expiry);` ends up calling `PayOffBridge(const PayOff& innerPayOff);`. I cannot figure out from where this gets called. How does the constructor for `VanillaOption` end up calling this?

My 2nd question is the constructor for `VanillaOption` which gets called from `main()` is

```
VanillaOption::VanillaOption(const PayOffBridge& ThePayOff_, double Expiry_): ThePayOff(ThePayOff_), Expiry(Expiry_)
{
}
```

What exactly does `ThePayOff(ThePayOff_)` do? That is, which constructor of `PayOffBridge` gets called, if at all, and what exactly does this syntax accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st answer**

`VanillaOption` expects `PayOffBridge` object as a constructor parameter. But, you pass `PayOffCall` object instead. Compiler looks for a way to construct temporary `PayOffBridge` object from given `PayOffCall` object.

It has `PayOffBridge(const PayOff& innerPayOff);` constructor. So, it needs a reference to `PayOff` object for construction. But, `PayOffCall` is derived from `PayOff`, so `const PayOffCall&` is implicitly converted into `const PayOff&` and you get `PayOffBridge` constructed.

**2nd answer**

`ThePayOff(ThePayOff_)` means object construction. For a start you should recognize types of these variables.

`const PayOffBridge& ThePayOff_` - input parameter

`PayOffBridge ThePayOff` - member of `VanilaOption`

So, `PayOffBridge` object is constructed from another `PayOffBridge` object. Obviously, copy constructor is called

`PayOffBridge(const PayOffBridge& original);`

Comment: Wow...I guess that's it then...the compiler goes down the list of possible constructors for `PayOffBridge` that could use `PayOffCall` Object...The one I encountered is the "closest" one...This opens another set of questions...what happens when there is a tie for the "closest" one?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification...this makes my previous comment moot.

Comment: @Tryer C++ has strict rules of which overloaded constructor or method should be called. If there are two or more constructors fit equally, you just get a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for `VanillaOption` that you use has an *[initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html)* to construct it's internal members. This is invoking the <strike>copy</strike> constructor for `PayoffBridge`, copying `ThePayoff_` into `ThePayoff`

```
VanillaOption::VanillaOption(const PayOffBridge& ThePayOff_, double Expiry_):
    ThePayOff(ThePayOff_), 
    Expiry(Expiry_)
{
}
```

The 'body' of this constructor is intentionally empty because all the work is done by the initialization list.

Comment: Hmm...but `PayOffBridge(const PayOff& innerPayOff)` is not a copy constructor, right? It applies to a `PayOffBridge` object yet its parameter is a `PayOff` object.

Comment: Oops. Yes, I'll correct that.But it doesn't make a real difference. Rember inheritance is about "is a", so your PayoffCall 'is a' PayOff', so that constructor can be used unambiguously.